# THREE.js: Sphere that morphs in response to mouse events

Tags: three.js

I'm new to Three.js.

**What I need to create:**
A sphere that stretches-out toward the cursor, as if it is reaching toward the screen.

*I was hoping to do this without using a model/Loader.  That is, I simply want to use the SphereGeometry constructor.*

I've read and re-read Three.js docs, viewed and reviewed Three.js' examples.  But, the more I read the more boggled I feel.

My question broken down:

1. *How would I interact with geometry vertices or faces with the cursor?*
2. *How do I isolate sphere vertices/faces in order to adjust their 3D position?*

Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, it has vertices. Yes, they will interact with the cursor, if you implement this behaviour in a script. No, there is no such out-of-box functionality in three.js, you have to code it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, @prisoner849.  What's the best approach to interacting with the individual vertices and faces of a sphere (or any geometry)?

Comment: There are many interactive examples: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=interactive

Comment: Yes, I've looked at those examples. It's the mapping or correlation of raycaster/cursor and the geometry's vertices where I'm stuck. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome :) Providing a live code example with a problem helps to get an answer.

Comment: @ErikK What have you tried? Do you have a live example of your attempt so far?